# Vue V-Bind:src always includes local server "localhost:8080"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

**Hi!** I receive data from the server by the type "/uploads/image.png", that is, the path to the file. But Vue add to path localhost:8000,
how can I replace localhost with the domain I need?

My problem:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F75rU.png)

my vue-config:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    devServer: {
        proxy : {
            '/': {
                target: 'http://localhost:1337'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set publicPath:

```js
publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '': 'http://localhost:1337/',
```